# How to use regular expressions for making dummies?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

For instance, I have reviews column and I want to extract words and create dummy variables based on them.

I use that but can't use regular expressions here:

```
df = df['reviews'].str.contains('good').astype(int)
```

How can I use regular expressions here for extracting good, goid, goof etc.

Comment: you can try `df['reviews'].str.extract('(your_favourite_regex)')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .map method after the .contains method. Here's a concise example:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2,3],
                  'review': ['this is a good one',
                            'this is a bad one',
                            'this one seems to be fine']})

df['review_good'] = df.review.str.contains('good').map({True: 1, False: 0})
```

Comment: I know that one when I name it and put in my df it is dummy but I want to use regular expressions